# Unable to download Web App code via 'Download as Zip' from Azure Dashboard

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have built a Web App Bot via Azure Dashboard. I have played around with the code using the online editor, but I really need to download it to work in Visual Studio.

Whenever I try - via multiple PCs - to download via

> Download source code Download your source code and develop locally
>   using your favorite IDE. You can publish your code back to the bot
>   when ready.
>
> **Download zip file**

I get the error:

> Failed to download the file. Error details: error 404 Not Found

What am I doing wrong? There's not much detail in the error. I'm sure I've been able to do this a while ago. Plenty of Google references on getting 404's uploading code TO Azure, but not downloading it :)

Answer (score 0):

When you created bot application in Azure also has created web application with the same name. You can download the source code from web app - it has the same codebase with the bot app.

Comment: Thank you, but where do I identify or find the web application? And where do I download that source code from? At the moment I'm selecting Web App Bot > Build > Download as Zip. When the bot is created, it creates an app service plan, a storage account, the web app bot, but I don't see a web application?

Comment: Interestingly, I just created a new web app bot using Azure, and I can download that source code fine using Web App Bot > Build > Download as Zip. So surely the method I'm using is correct, it's just the outcome that isn't correct?

Comment: You use the correct method and Web App Bot > Build > Download as Zip is a right way, but you can use also a workaround if something goes wrong.